# Views switches to another view on apply or any change

Tags: 7, views, javascript

When I'm working on a block display in Views on Drupal 7, and hit the "Apply" button, I'm taken to the master (or first view), instead of staying on the block display that I'm working on.

How do I fix this behaviour and remain on the correct display when applying settings?

Answer (score 1):

I finally tracked it down to a setting in Views (where it shows all of the views) and the Settings tab. Under the Advanced Option here, I was able to turn off a "Disable Javascript on Views" setting that had somehow gotten turned on. The Ajax function was not firing and the main URL was resetting for every update of any kind. This meant jumping between views for every change of any field whatsoever.

That setting fixed everything though, so I'm posting in case anyone else has the issue and can't find a reason.

[image]